# I cannot deploy to vercel because I get the error: Specified images.domains should be an Array of strings received invalid values ()

Tags: heroku, deployment, next.js, vercel, nextjs-image

When I deploy on vercel I get this error

> Build error occurred
> 14:34:33.017    Error: Specified images.domains should be an Array of strings received invalid values ().

To get images showing on my screen locally I did these settings:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN,
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN,
  },

  images: {
    deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
    imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96],
    domains: [process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN],
    path: "/_next/image",
    loader: "default",
  },

  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

In my env.local I have put this

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL= ...
NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN=localhost
```

I call my images with out of fetch like so

```
const Potato = ({ assets}) => { 
 <Image
   src={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL + assets.hat.svg.url}
   width={assets.hat.svg.width}
   height={assets.hat.svg.height}
 />
}
```

Locally I can see the images, However I also get this error in my console.log when I run my app locally. I don't know how or why. Since my images load just fine. Maybe this is the reason that Vercel does not work but I don't know if the two are related.
[image]

All the settings above are almost exactly copy pasted from this video (watch from minute 10-16):
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o06N-q2awQA)

What I have tried so far:
Adding NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN in the environment variables on Vercel with the name of my Heroku backend as value (just like I did for NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL), which deployed fine, but I got a 500 server error. But then I also don't know how I should fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `.env.local`, you don't need to put `env`/`publicRuntimeConfig` in your `next.config.js`. [You can remove those](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).

You also don't need to set `path` and `loader` for images if you're using the default. The only required value would be `domains` - and then you have the option for `deviceSizes` and `imageSizes` of course.

You are correct that you'll need to add your [Environment Variables](https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables) inside the Vercel project.